# Durandal dialogs hiding the body scrollbar

Tags: dialog, durandal

I was reading about [Dialog contexts](http://durandaljs.com/documentation/Showing-Message-Boxes-And-Modals.html) and came across the statement "While the dialog is visible, scroll bars are hidden on the body/html." I would like to modify this behavior. My app has a background image and I'm keeping the scrollbar visible at all times to keep it from re-sizing the image.

The docs I found on dialog contexts looks really bare. Could anybody point me in the right direction to remove or modify the behavior that is hiding the scroll bar?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Well, I found a work around. I just changed the `html { overflow-y: scroll }` to have a `!important` on it.

Edit: Another quick solution was to just modify plugins/dialog.js by removing this line:`$("html").css("overflow-y", "hidden");` - obvious drawback is that you're modifying the durandal code

Comment: Just so you know, there is nothing wrong in principal with overriding all of Durandal's default CSS.  It simply means that you'll be taking control of styling yourself.  That's what we did.  Also, I voted your question and answer up.  Be sure to mark your own answer as the correct one.